# Composite key as foreign key of multiple tables

Tags: database-design, erd

[image]

On Entity1 table, could I merge the two "a" field in a single field ?

Comment: Yes you should have one column `a` in Entity1. That is, if you want the two relationships to Entity4 (that go through Entity2 and 3) to refer to the same "a".

Comment: Yes both relationship 3 and 5 refer to the same value of "a". 
Doubt: if I will remove all records from table Entity3, I won't nullify both "a" and "c" on table "Entity1" because the "a" field is also part of another Relationship (r.3). So is it correct to model a single "a" field in table Entity1 ??

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the data model.

If it is possible and correct for a row in table 1 to have a relationship with rows in tables 2 & 3 with different values of `a` then you must keep the two values separate as you potentially need to different values.

If this should not be possible (i.e. makes no sense for the situation you are modelling) then not only *could* you use the same column, but you *should* as keeping two copies of data that should be identical can lead, via bugs or other human error, to consistency errors. The same column can participate in any number of keys and indexes so that will not block you from doing this.

Without more information on what you are modelling, it is not possible to give a more definite answer.

Comment: Both relationships 5 and 3 are on the same value of "a". What I don't know if I could have two relationship (5, 3) that share a field ("a") which is part of a composite foreign key.

Comment: Yes, a single column can participate in any number of indexes/keys/constraints, so there isn't a limit there that would lock you. I'll reword to make that clearer. For example syntax based on your diagram see https://pastebin.com/5YZs9DmX (I'll not add it all to the answer as hopefully that is now clear enough without the extra noise)

Comment: Here some doubts.  With a single "a" field on Entity1, could Relationship5 be optional and Relationship3 mandatory ?
If I can design my model with a single "a" field in Entity1, if I will remove all records from table Entity3, how can I nullify the Relationship5 ? I couldn't  nullify both "a" and "c" fields on table "Entity1" because the "a" field is also part of the Relationship3. 
What do you think about ?

Comment: @Andrea: if E1.c is defined as NOT NULL and E1.a isn't then relationship 5 becomes mandatory without making relationship 3 mandatory: you would be forced to pick a valid value for E1.a to satisfy the FK enforcing R5 but that could not force you to complete the composite key for R3. _This may be SQL Server specific, and may even be a completely "undefined" behaviour I've not checked if the relevant standard of MS's documentation define a behaviour for this sort of case_. See https://pastebin.com/uQv0sUHZ for an updated worked example.

Comment: @David_Spillett you are right, I have read your snippet. My test have confirmed the same conclusion: the NULL value in the "Entity1.c" field  stops the dbs to enforce the FK in the Relationship5 and the integrity constraint is not honored. So I think that there is a design fault in my ER. So I have elaborated a possible solution in the following answer. It would be useful to everyone to have a your comment on the point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remarks and solution:

1) As remarked by David in the above answer, the same field (eg: "a") can participate in any number of relationships.

2) Composite foreign key's fields should be always not nullable. Otherwise the reference integrity constraints would not be correctly applied (or even not applied at all) by the dbms.

3) If the relationships which share the same fields (eg: "Relationship2" and "Relationship3" in the first diagram, see above) should be optional (not mandatory) the right solution could be the following:

[image]

Comment: This looks like one plausible solution to the problem. But you'll have to include `a` in relation `Entity1` as well.

Comment: Should I have to include the "a" field only in Entity1 ? So I need to add a new relationship between Entity1 and Entity4 ?

Comment: Another clarification: 
The value of "a" in Entity6 should be the same which is in Entity7. But i don't know how to enforce that rule.

Comment: See my comment above: *"But you'll have to include a in relation Entity1 as well."*

Comment: To spell ypercube's point out more explicitly: If `a` is a required property in E1 then it can be part if a composite FK for R5 and R6 (referencing d+a in both cases), forcing `a` to be the same for the same value of `d` where found in E6 and E7. That should work assuming there is not need to support floating examples of Entity1 (by "floating" I mean with respect to this diagram - they exist to have meaning elsewhere but don't (yet) have any relationship to the other entities being discussed so currently have no value for `a`),